# a command put a key on stdout and the next after | uses the key taken from stdin to open db

Tags: bash

I have a command which outputs a key with `pass  key/ffff.kdbx` and a second command which takes a key from stdin to open a database `keepassxc --pw-stdin`. I have very little experience with bash and expected that I can connect the two command with a pipe:

`pass  key/ffff.kdbx | keepassxc --pw-stdin`

The command results in the opening of the `keepasxc` program expecting input, but not getting the output from the first one as inpu. The first produces the expected output:

```
pass  key/ffff.kdbx
xxxxxxxx
```

What is wrong with my obiously naive approach and what must be changed?

The idea is to use a key stored in the Unix password manager to open the KeepassXC password manager (which integrates better with a browser than pass). Thank you with help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `--pw-stdin` only works if you also specify which `kdbx` to open. The following should work:

```
pass key/ffff.kdbx | keepassxc --pw-stdin /path/to/your/database.kdbx
```

You might also want to use `nohup keepassxc ... &` such that the bash process can terminate while `keepassxc` keeps running.

Comment: perfect ! I was expecting the problem with my lack of understanding bash and not a problem of the keepassxc commmand. My bad; thank you!

Comment: I tried to add `nohup` but are confused. I have now `pass keepass/fromfirefox.kdbx | nohup keepassxc --pw-stdin Data/fromfirefox.kdbx &` and receive a warning `nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'`. I read some older posts of `nohup`, but are still confused. What is the best way to include `nohup` to have the opening of `keepassxc` wait till `pass` is ready (after having received the passphrase)?

Comment: You used `nohup` correctly. That warning is normal. `keepassxc` still consumes stdin. Only its *terminal output* is printed into the file `nohup.out` instead of the current terminal. You can disable this warning by redirecting the output manually; `nohup ... > /dev/null &` throws away all terminal output.